# How to get active QDockWidget in QQMainWindow

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a QMainWindow containing several QDockWidgets. Each DockWidget contains several other 3rd party Widgets (I don't have access to the source). Some of these Widgets consume focus and mouse events.
My problem is to determine when the user clicks on one of the DockWidgets. Installing an eventFilter on the DockWidget won't work, because some of the DockWidget's childs consume the relevant events.
Is there a way to determine the "active" DockWidget?

Comment: If DockWidget's child stole the event, can you go up by widgets hierarchy until you find the parent DockWindow?

Comment: My problem is, that when the 3ed party widget steels the event, my dockWidget is not informed, that an event occured. I don't have the access to the actual widget consuming the event. It is only included as a child of the DockWidget via an interface library. It's the DockWidget which should detect, that in its boundarys a click occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the `QWidget` that has the focus using `QApplication::focusWidget()`.

and you could use something like:

```
QWidget* wid = QApplication::focusWidget();
QDockWidget* dock = 0;
while (dock != mainWindow && wid != 0)
{
    dock = qobject_cast<QDockWidget*>(wid);
    if (dock)
        break; // its a QDockWidget
    wid = wid->parent();
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. For my application I use now the signal `QApplication::focusChanged ( QWidget * old, QWidget * now )` and check if the widget `now` is a child of my `QDockWidget`.

Comment: cool idea but may cause unwanted function calls due the fact that any change in the focus will start the loop again.